# Automated backup of Apache & MySQL sites to live remote servers

Tags: linux, backup, apache-http-server, rsync, lamp

I'm looking for a nice utility to maintain backup instances of my LAMP-based web applications. (LAMP = Linux Apache MySQL PHP {don't care about the PHP part}). I want the backup instances to be functional, so in the event of a failure on the src copy machine, the backup instances can be used as a drop-in replacement.

Ideally, I'd like a utility with a web ui that lets me provide ssh credentials, source and destination information and will go off and periodically push copies of my LAMP sites to whatever backup locations I specify - automatically.

I'm considering just writing this myself. But it seems to me like something that must exist. Then again, I can imagine how no one's bothered to make a UI for something like this as it's so simple to do with cron jobs & rsync.

Comment: Perhaps we should move this over to ServerFault instead?

Comment: I was about to say `cron` with `rsync` up until you got to "web interface".

Comment: @new123456: Heh, yeah, I know... I'm meaning for this to be used by admin staff that have panic attacks at something they can't manage from a GUI in Windows. Ohh well.. :)

Comment: Heh, I was just googling this topic again and ran in to this question, started reading and was like "yeah! This is what I'm talking about.." then noticed no answers and that this was a question posted by me a while ago. Sigh.. lol